# Is there a way to change brush fuzziness in paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

Is there a way to make the texture paint brush fuzzy like in Photoshop?  I've tried playing with the Tools/Curve editor, but this seems to only affect the sharpness of the edge of brush stroke - most of the stroke is still thick.  It would be nice to have the curve falloff affect the entire brush head.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what the *curve* does:

[image]

Comment: It's not working for me.  I can get a similar image with the brush preview when I press F, but when I try to draw anything, it comes out flat.

Comment: @kitfox Huh, that's odd.. Is it possible you could upload a .blend with your painting settings?

Comment: You can grab a copy here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B65Z2rSspR06Y2hZY1NqcGU5U1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @kitfox Made some changes to the curve: [blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CNXBSWld0RmVhZVE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @kitfox Works fine for me..